# Margins after seemingly unrelated regression too slow in Stata

Tags: stata, margins

I have a 3 million obs data set. I need to estimate a LPM with SUR, and get the marginal effects.

I used `gsem... vce(cluster x)`, then `margins, ... force`. But it takes a very long time to get the margins result (more than 2 hours). I do need to standard errors for CI, so I can't not use the `nose` option.

Is there other ways I can improve the speed?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `lincom` to calculate the margins yourself.

Comment: @Wouter Do you have an example how i can do that? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exact code depends on which marginal effects you mean exactly. You can calculate partial effects with `lincom`, which will most likely by faster than `margins`.

As an example, suppose we estimate this model:
[image: model]

The partial effect of x1 on y can be obtained by taking the partial derivative with respect to x1:
[image: derivative]

We can get the effect of x1 on y at the means of x2 and x3 by plugging in the means. To do this in Stata:

```
// Get data
webuse regress

// Run the regression
qui reg y c.x1##c.(x2 x3)

// Get the sample means of x2 and x3 
sum x2 if e(sample), meanonly
scalar m_x2 = r(mean)
sum x3 if e(sample), meanonly
scalar m_x3 = r(mean)

// Calculate partial effect
lincom x1 + m_x2 * c.x1#c.x2 + m_x3*c.x1#c.x3
```

Result:

```
. lincom x1 + m_x2 * c.x1#c.x2 + m_x3*c.x1#c.x3

 ( 1)  x1 - .2972973*c.x1#c.x2 + 3019.459*c.x1#c.x3 = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
           y |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |   1.409372   1.005254     1.40   0.163    -.5778255    3.396569
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, this is the same as the results obtained by margins:

```
. qui reg y c.x1##c.(x2 x3)

. margins, dydx(x1) atmeans

Conditional marginal effects                    Number of obs     =        148
Model VCE    : OLS

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : x1
at           : x1              =    3.014865 (mean)
               x2              =   -.2972973 (mean)
               x3              =    3019.459 (mean)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          x1 |   1.409372   1.005254     1.40   0.163    -.5778256    3.396569
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's a speed comparison showing that `lincom` is 14 times faster than `margins` in this case with 3 million observations:

```
clear
webuse regress
expand 20271

gen lincom = .
gen margins = .
qui reg y c.x1##c.(x2 x3)

forval i = 1/50 {

    timer clear
    
    timer on 1
    sum x2 if e(sample), meanonly
    scalar m_x2 = r(mean)
    sum x3 if e(sample), meanonly
    scalar m_x3 = r(mean)
    lincom x1 + m_x2 * c.x1#c.x2 + m_x3*c.x1#c.x3
    timer off 1

    timer on 2
    margins, dydx(x1) atmeans
    timer off 2
    
    timer list
    replace lincom = r(t1) in `i'
    replace margins = r(t2) in `i'
}

ttest lincom == margins
di "On average, lincom is " %4.2f `=r(mu_2) / r(mu_1)' " times faster than margins with `=_N' observations"
// On average, lincom is 13.88 times faster than margins with 3000108 observations
```